# How to use lattice modifier to deform a mesh without the texture/UV map deforming

Tags: lattice

I am trying to create a replication of a vehicle. How can I manipulate the lattice so the texture doesn't deform? The image below is without a texture map.

[image]

Comment: You could just UV unwrap the mesh after finishing the modelling. This would then not be affected by the lattice deform.

Comment: Just tried that and it worked great. Thanks AtomicTranq